# GRASS - v.clean Conflation - How to snap a layer to a base layer

Tags: grass-gis, topology

Someone told me in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67134/14426) that GRASS GIS can handle multilayer topology, what I have not found any information about. I am not a specialist of GRASS GIS so I would need help with that if its really feasible.

What I am trying to do is to snap a layer to a base layer, so when both share the sames boundaries they would be topologically snapped.

The base layer is the official cities boundaries of my country. The layer to be snapped is made of cities subdivisions but may not always fit.

[image]

I have to be sure that the base layer would no be modified at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for this is "vector conflation". Currently under development for GRASS GIS, see [here](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Talk%3aGRASS_Community_Sprint_Prague_2013#Tereza_Fiedlerov.C3.A1). Manually you can use the [digitizer](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Vector_Digitizer) for it which supports base maps.

Comment: is the digitizer similar to the vertex snapper of ArcGIS 10?